# Jews believing in Jesus after his second coming

Tags: source-identification, jews, eschatology

According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming#Islam), all People of the Book will believe in Jesus (pbuh) and thus become Muslims.

> Eventually, Jesus will slay the Antichrist Dajjal, and then everyone
>   from the People of the Book (ahl al-kitāb, referring to Jews and
>   Christians) will believe in him. Thus, there will be one community,
>   that of Islam. Sahih Muslim, 41:7023

However, the reference given (41:7023) is broken and perhaps this numbering has been deprecated. It may refer to [this hadith](https://muflihun.com/muslim/41/7023) but it does not say what the article alludes to.

Please share a reference of hadith(s) which says that Jews will believe in him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadith that is quoted in the Wikipedia article is the one narrated by 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr, and it is indeed in Sahih Mulsim, Book 41, [Hadith 7023](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2940a), according to one of the numbering systems.

Having said that, I am more inclined to believe that the hadith they meant to refer to is this one:

> وَحَدَّثَنَاهُ عَبْدُ الأَعْلَى بْنُ حَمَّادٍ، وَأَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ وَزُهَيْرُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ قَالُوا حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ بْنُ عُيَيْنَةَ، ح وَحَدَّثَنِيهِ حَرْمَلَةُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، أَخْبَرَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي يُونُسُ، ح وَحَدَّثَنَا حَسَنٌ الْحُلْوَانِيُّ، وَعَبْدُ بْنُ حُمَيْدٍ، عَنْ يَعْقُوبَ بْنِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ بْنِ سَعْدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي، عَنْ صَالِحٍ، كُلُّهُمْ عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، بِهَذَا الإِسْنَادِ وَفِي رِوَايَةِ ابْنِ عُيَيْنَةَ ‏"‏ إِمَامًا مُقْسِطًا وَحَكَمًا عَدْلاً ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَفِي رِوَايَةِ يُونُسَ ‏"‏ حَكَمًا عَادِلاً ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَلَمْ يَذْكُرْ ‏"‏ إِمَامًا مُقْسِطًا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَفِي حَدِيثِ صَالِحٍ ‏"‏ حَكَمًا مُقْسِطًا ‏"‏ كَمَا قَالَ اللَّيْثُ ‏.‏ وَفِي حَدِيثِهِ مِنَ الزِّيَادَةِ ‏"‏ وَحَتَّى تَكُونَ السَّجْدَةُ الْوَاحِدَةُ خَيْرًا مِنَ الدُّنْيَا وَمَا فِيهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثُمَّ يَقُولُ أَبُو هُرَيْرَةَ اقْرَءُوا إِنْ شِئْتُمْ ‏{‏ وَإِنْ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ إِلاَّ لَيُؤْمِنَنَّ بِهِ قَبْلَ مَوْتِهِ‏}‏ الآيَةَ
>
> The same hadith is transmitted from Zuhri with the same chain of transmission. But in the tradition narrated by Ibn 'Uyaina the words are: "impartial leader and just judge" and in the tradition narrated by Yunus: the" judge judging with justice" and" impartial leader" are not mentioned. And in the hadith narrated by Salih like the one transmitted by Laith the words are:" impartial judge". And in the hadith transmitted by Ziyad the words are:" Till one sajda is better than the worldand what it contains. Then Abu Huraira used to say," recite" if you like: Not one of the People of the Book will fail to believe in him before his death.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim 1/297](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155b)</sub>

This hadith is also in Sahih [Al-Bukhari 60/118](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/60/118/). The verse from the Qur'an quoted by Abu Huraira at the end of the hadith is:

> وَإِن مِّنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ إِلَّا لَيُؤْمِنَنَّ بِهِ قَبْلَ مَوْتِهِ ۖ وَيَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ يَكُونُ عَلَيْهِمْ شَهِيدًا
>
> And there is none from the People of the Scripture but that he will surely believe in Jesus before his death. And on the Day of Resurrection he will be against them a witness.
>
> <sub>— [Qur'an 4:159](https://quran.com/4/159/)</sub>

In *Al-Jami' Li Ahkam Al-Qur'an* (Arabic: [الجامع لأحكام القرآن](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1149&bk_no=48&flag=1)) tafsir, [Al-Qurtubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qurtubi) mentions:

> ذلك أنه ليس أحد من أهل الكتاب اليهود والنصارى إلا ويؤمن بعيسى عليه السلام إذا عاين الملك ، ولكنه إيمان لا ينفع؛ لأنه إيمان عند اليأس وحين التلبس بحالة الموت؛ فاليهودي يقر في ذلك الوقت بأنه رسول الله، والنصراني يقر بأنه كان رسول الله
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> This is because no one from the People of the Scripture but will believe in Jesus when they see the angel [of death] with their eyes. But this belief will not benefit them, as it is belief at the time of desperation, at the moment of death. The Jew will admit, at that time, that he [Jesus] is a messenger of Allah, and the Christian will admit that he is a messenger of Allah.

I could not find any other hadith in Sahih Muslim that refers to the matter of the Jews believing in Jesus other than the one above.

On a separate note, there are several numbering systems for the books of hadith. For instance, Sahih Al-Bukhari has a few numbering systems, e.g., Al-'Alamiyyah (Arabic: العالمية), and Fat'h Al-Bari (Arabic: فتح الباري). Sahih Muslim also has two common numbering systems: Al-'Alamiyyah (Arabic: العالمية), and 'Abdel-Baqi (Arabic: عبد الباقي). The same applies for other books of hadith.

The hadith that you mentioned (41/7023) is actually number 23/2940 according to the Sahih Muslim as compiled by [Al-Hakim Al-Nisapuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hakim_Nishapuri) (Arabic: أبو عبد الله الحاكم النيسابوري), following the numbering system of Muhammad Fu'ad 'Abdel-Baqi (Arabic: [محمد فؤاد عبد الباقي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D9%81%D8%A4%D8%A7%D8%AF_%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%8A)), who specialized in classification and taxonomy. This is why it is important when referring to a hadith to quote the words (preferably in both English and Arabic), as a reference by number alone may be confusing or may not allow readers to find the correct hadith. The hadith numbering was not introduced by the original compilers (in this case, Al-Hakim Al-Nisapuri), but rather by the editors (in this case, Muhammad Fu'ad 'Abdel-Baqi); it is relatively recent in hadith books.